# Binding data in type (dict) is not supported

Tags: python, sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write json object into a particular column of my sql table

```
variant_str = response.json()

print(con.cursor().execute('INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (JSON_STR) VALUES (?)', (variant_str,)))
```

Here, the `variant_str` is of type `dict`.

I get an error that:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 252004: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; 255001: Binding data in type (dict) is not supported.
```

The table's ddl where I am trying to load the data is this:

```
create or replace TABLE TEST_TABLE (
    JSON_STR VARIANT
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use `?` as the placeholder for parameter binding:

```
import snowflake.connector

snowflake.connector.paramstyle='qmark'
```

Insert using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT PARSE_JSON(...)`

```
con.cursor().execute('INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (JSON_STR) SELECT PARSE_JSON(?)'
                     , (variant_str))
```

where `variant_str` is a valid JSON string

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `response.json()`, use `response.text()`. `json()` decodes the JSON into dictionaries and lists, but you need to store the raw JSON string into the table.

Comment: Then I still get an error while executing the sql:  ```Error not all arguments converted during string formatting```

Comment: Are you sure Snowflake uses `?` as the placeholder? Some databases (e.g. MySQL) use `%s`.

Comment: You might be correct here. But if I use the ```%s``` syntax, I still get this: ```Expression type does not match column data type, expecting VARIANT but got VARCHAR(69205) for column JSON_STR```. If I go back and change the ```response.json()``` to ```response.text```, I would once again get the binding data type error

Comment: The column type is originally Variant

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Snowflake, but I think you need `to_variant(%s)`

Comment: Qmark binding is supported. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#data-type-mappings-for-qmark-and-numeric-bindings

Comment: @x89 That error is one that comes from the `.format()` function, not prepared statement function binding.